# GlusterFS command for getting replication completeness status

Tags: glusterfs

I use GlusterFS in high availability cluster. I need some functionality for getting replication status (replication completeness status). In other words I need to know that cluster now is in protected state (in terms of disk replication) and in the case of the master node failover all the data will not be lost.
I already tried *gluster volume status*, *gluster peer status*, but they only provide information about connection.

P.S.
For instance in drbd there was a command *drbdadm status* which provides information *peer-disk:UpToDate* (which means that replication process completed).
Is there any builtin GlusterFS function that can provide me with required information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gluster volume heal <VOLNAME> info` is the command for checking pending heals in replicate volumes. See https://gluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Troubleshooting/heal-info-and-split-brain-resolution/ for more info.